# Prevent or Mute "Device Location Shared" notification from showing

Tags: android-device-manager, location-services

Starting yesterday (March 23 2015) whenever I access Android Device Manager page I get a notification prompt on my phone saying:

"**Device location shared**. Android Device Manager located this device"

I really don't want this to show up. In case someone steals my phone, I don't want them to know I know where they are located.

I don't want to know other alternative apps to do this (as I already have airdroid which I can use to do this) I just want to be able to mute this notification.

Does anybody knows how to mute this  notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To disable application notifications for versions prior to 5.1**:

1. Open "settings".
2. In the device section of the settings menu, choose "**apps**" from the list.
3. Choose "all" from the menu to show a list of all installed applications.
4. Locate the application, in your case Android Device Manager, it may be labelled "Device Manager".
5. Highlight the application, then select "**app info**"
6. In the App Info screen, uncheck the "**Show notifications**" box.

You should no longer receive notifications for the the application.

Please note that not all applications enable to uncheck the "show notification" check box. At least not those on LG G3 device.

**To disable application notifications for version 5.1**:

1. Open "Settings".
2. Under "Quick Settings" open "**Sounds and notifications**".
3. Under "Notifications" open "**App notifications**".
4. Select the desired application from the list.
5. Use the on/off switch for "Block notifications". Turn on to block the application's notifications.

Comment: Android 5.1 at least does not seem to have any "Android Device Manager" or similar. They've probably hidden it with other services or disallow removing notofications

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to include steps for 5.1.

Comment: In 5.1, you can also long-press the notification itself, which will change the notification into the name of the app, plus an "i" icon. The "i" takes you directly to the notification setting for that particular app.  In 6.0, the same long-press adds a bell icon next to the "i" icon.  The bell toggles the notification setting for that app directly without going over to settings.